# All links for Mediawiki Special Pages do nothing (lowercase 's')

Tags: php, mediawiki

Im not sure what has happened but all of the links to special pages on the wiki have broken. For example "Preferences" at the top of the page which should be "Special:Preferences" is showing up as "special:Preferences". I can access the page if i type it directly into the browser but the links are displaying incorrectly. Any idea how to fix this?

When i click the link in opera i get the following error

"...unable to open the link since no application associated with "special:" protocol was found on your system

To further expand on this. All article pages work correctly. When i hover over the link the destination url shows up with the domain name. e.g. wiki.domain.com/pageName. When i hover over the Special page link it just shows up as special:pageName.

I need to find out how to make the server name show up in front of the special pages.

Answer (score 0):

Are the article links also broken? If so, it seems like you have an empty [`$wgArticlePath`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgArticlePath), reset it to a safe value (depends on how the wiki is set up, the safest but ugliest one is `"{$wgScript}?title=$1"`).

Comment: Its just the special pages. I have looked into it further and when I hover over article links it displays the full server name e.g. wiki.domain.com/page name but when I hover over a special link it just says special:Pagename. I tried modifying the htm using the chrome dev tools and I was able to click the link when I manually added the server name

Comment: Is the skin non-standard/outdated?

Comment: How do I tell if its outdated? Its the standard wikipedia style skin